# merge multiple keywords into a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, random, merge

i am trying to write a program to take a random amount of multiple keywords from a String[] and merge them together into a String

```
    String keywords = "max,Max,Pro,pro,XS,xs,Xs,XR,xr,Xr,X,6,7,8,10,11,SE,se,Se,Plus,plus";
    String[] keywordArray = keywords.split(",");
    Random keywordSelector = new Random();
    int keywordIndex = keywordSelector.nextInt(21);
    String title = keywordArray[keywordIndex];          

    System.out.println("iPhone " + title);
```

current output example: `iPhone X`

how can i change the code so that i can achieve desired output example?: `iPhone X 6 Max Pro 10 11 SE`

Comment: Do you care if there are repeats or is order important?

Comment: order important

Comment: You need to be more specific.  A random answer could be `iPhone max Max pro Pro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could utilize an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to achieve what you desire without duplicates.

Your code could like this:

```
        String keywords = "max,Max,Pro,pro,XS,xs,Xs,XR,xr,Xr,X,6,7,8,10,11,SE,se,Se,Plus,plus";
        ArrayList<String> keywordArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(keywords.split(",")));
        Random keywordSelector = new Random();
        String title = "iPhone ";
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            int keywordIndex = keywordSelector.nextInt(keywordArray.size());
            String keyword = keywordArray.get(keywordIndex);       
            title = title + keyword + " ";
            keywordArray.remove(keyword);
        }
        System.out.println(title);
```

Basiclly create a modifiable list, pick a keyword from it an remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  You need to categorize the different aspects of the phone.

- categories separated by `:`
- within categories separated by `,`

```
String keywords = "max,Max:Pro,pro:XS,xs,Xs,XR,xr,Xr,X:6,7,8,10,11:SE,se,Se:Plus,plus";

String [] elements = keywords.split(":");
String[][] categories = new String[elements.length][];

// create arrays of categories.
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      categories[i] = elements[i].split(",");
}

Random r = new Random();
String title = "";

// generate a random one based on each array size.
for (String[] c : categories) {
      int idx = r.nextInt(c.length);
      title += c[idx] + " ";
}  

System.out.println("iPhone " + title);
```

Prints something similar to (it will be different each time);

```
iPhone Max pro Xr 6 se plus
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using streams?

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    String keywords = "max,Max,Pro,pro,XS,xs,Xs,XR,xr,Xr,X,6,7,8,10,11,SE,se,Se,Plus,plus";
    String[] keywordArray = keywords.split(",");
    System.out.print("iPhone");

    long numberOfRandomKeywords = 5L;
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = keywordArray.length + 1;
    int[] randomIndexes = new Random().ints(numberOfRandomKeywords, lowerBound, upperBound).toArray();

    Stream<String> keywordStreams = Arrays.stream(keywordArray);
    keywordStreams.forEachOrdered( x -> {
        Map<String, Boolean> seenKeywords = new HashMap<>();
        for(int index : randomIndexes){
            if(keywordArray[index] == x && !seenKeywords.containsKey(x)) {
                System.out.print(" " + x);
                seenKeywords.put(x, true);
            }
        }
    }); 

    Long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("\nTime taken: " + (endTime - startTime)/1_000_000 + " ms");
}
```

Sample Output:

> iPhone Xs xr 6 10 Plus
>   Time taken: 52 ms